# Weird error occur in my android studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

Weird error occur in my android studio. When i start android studio project loaded successfully but when i copy the code from one java file to another it automatically start indexing and shows IDE error.

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.currentStackTrace(DebugUtil.java:497)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelper.stubTreeAndIndexDoNotMatch(StubProcessingHelper.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.inconsistencyDetected(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:172)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:162)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$1.process(StubIndexImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$StubIdListContainerAction.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:582)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$StubIdListContainerAction.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:570)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.ValueContainer.forEach(ValueContainer.java:81)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.doProcessStubs(StubIndexImpl.java:252)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:223)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:145)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:135)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaFullClassNameIndex.get(JavaFullClassNameIndex.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClassInIndex(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFinderImpl.findClass(PsiElementFinderImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.doFindClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.fromString(PackageClassConverter.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.fromString(PackageClassConverter.java:51)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.getValueInner(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.getOrCalcValue(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$552d11bb.getValue(<generated>)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomUtil.findComponentDeclarationInManifest(AndroidDomUtil.java:440)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.findDeclarationInManifest(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.getLazyItemsForClass(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.getMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.doGetLineMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:36)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.SlowLineMarkersPass.addLineMarkers(SlowLineMarkersPass.java:78)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.SlowLineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(SlowLineMarkersPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:67)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:444)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1180)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:432)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:408)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:206)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:858)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1687)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1642)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
```

Comment: Did u try Build >> Clean Project in android studio?

Comment: If clean didn't help then try "File" -> "Invalidate cache and restart".